# Can't resolve 'otp-input-react' in my D:\project\app\src

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I am trying what I am doing is wrong but didn't find any.Tried to uninstall and reinstall the package then also it is not working here are the images for more clearer idea

[image: Error in terminal]

[image: Component Where I am using the otp-input-react]
[image: Package.json]
[image: Error in browser]

Comment: As far as I can tell, I see you installed `otp-input-react`, but isn't it suposed to be `react-otp-input`? try doing: `npm install --save react-otp-input` and change the name in your inports to: `import OtpInput from 'react-otp-input';`. [Source here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-otp-input)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per React 18 you may catch a dependency error.
My fix was: `npm install --force react-otp-input`